# Titanium build failed

Tags: ios, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app with iOS module added. I wanted some to methods to be executed so I created a proxy class with a method (id) doSomething;
I saved the changes to the module and repackaged it - so the olde version is rewritten. Now while trying to build a project I get an error:

> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
>
> [ERROR] :     Ld build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test normal i386
>
> [ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test normal x86_64
>
> [ERROR] :  (2 failures)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error most likely happens because the `.framework` file is not linked correctly. Ensure it is linked in `Build Phases`, as well as in you `module.xcconfig` like this:

`FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=$(SRCROOT)/../../modules/iphone/ti.googlemaps/1.0.0/platform "~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/ti.googlemaps/1.0.0/platform"`

OTHER_LDFLAGS =$(inherited) -framework Accelerate -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework ImageIO /usr/lib/libz.dylib /usr/lib/libc++.dylib /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GoogleMaps

If that still does not work, please link the module you are working on.